# Maven - Ranges in Snapshot Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to specify a particular version of a snapshot dependency, but with a range included?

I'm depending on a library (LibGDX) that has been stuck on `1.0-SNAPSHOT` for months, and has introduced breaking changes.

I can specify a particular snapshot version number such as `1.0-20140319.231735-366`. I'm using properties and the timestamp after the date varies between modules from the same project, so I'd like to be able to use `gdx-1.0-20140319.*` or similar.

Is the specification of ranges possible when referencing snapshots, or does this only work for release versions?

Comment: I would expect the range mechanism is quite agnostic to whether the qualifier is a timestamp, `SNAPSHOT` or something entirely different. Perhaps you should just try specing a `gdx` version of `[1.0-20140319,)` i.e. greater or equal to `1.0-20140319`. I'm curious about the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

The usual `[1,9)` style syntax doesn't work.